# Gtmetrix Rest Api Get Specific Results

Tags: php

i've been developing for my website which is , and to the point, i need to know how to fetch gtmetrix result from api, for example i want fetch results.html_bytes,
here's some code from gtmetrix

```
$testid = $test->get_test_id();
echo "Test completed succesfully with ID $testid\n";
$results = $test->results();
foreach ($results as $result => $data) {
   echo "$result : $data";

}
```

and result is

```
"results":{
    "page_load_time":"522",
    "html_bytes":"3395",
    "page_elements":"16",
    "report_url":"http://gtmetrix.com/reports/gtmetrix.com/Cz0AQOjf",
    "html_load_time":"87",
    "page_bytes":"89229",
    "pagespeed_score":"95",
    "yslow_score":"98"
}
```

what i want is just show the "html_bytes":"3395", 
and for the information the api can be found here http://gtmetrix.com/api/

hope for help

thanks

Comment: So what problem are you having? Can you show what you've tried and why that failed?

Comment: yeah, i use the code from gtmetrix gtmetrix.com/api/library/php/Services_WTF_Test.php and this http://gtmetrix.com/api/library/php/example.php

Comment: and yes, its work perfectly, but i just wanna show specific result, how can i do it?

Comment: @MuliaRifaiAroyan what specific result?

Comment: for example, just wanna show "pagespeed_score":"95", not the others,

Comment: `foreach ($results as $result => $data) {
   echo "pagespeed_score:". $data["pagespeed_score"];
}`

Comment: thanks emil, but im afraid there's problem, 
Warning: Illegal string offset 'pagespeed_score' in C:\xampp\htdocs\domain\speed2.php on line 56
pagespeed_score:9

what is that emil? sorry i just lack of logic for php, or im use localhost(xampp) and the result wont work?

Answer (score 1):

The `foreach` is for iterating over all the parts of the result, if all you want is the "html_bytes" just access it directly instead.

#### Like so:

```
$results = $test->results();
echo "html_bytes: " . $results['html_bytes'];
```

#### Output:

```
html_bytes: 3395
```